# Get stored procedure table information

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, datatable, sql-server-2012

Is it possible to get the column name/types from a stored procedure in an empty DataTable without calling the stored procedure?
This stored procedures also have parameters which I dont want to provide.

Is this possible or do I have to rethink my approach?

Comment: Which version of SQL server?

Comment: I should really write my questions more carefully, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Sql Server 2012 they introduced a function called *dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object* which does exactly what you want. As long as your procedure only is returning one result set.

```
SELECT name, system_type_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object
(
  OBJECT_ID('master.sys.sp_who'), 
  NULL
);
```

Another option is to use FMTONLY and then call the procedure. Executing this will get you an empty datatable with the correct column names.
In this case you would need to supply the parameters for the stored procedure.

```
SET FMTONLY ON;
exec sp_who
```

FMTONLY is deprecated as of Sql Server 2012 so I would avoid it if possible.

Comment: is the FMTONLY ON per connection or does this setting cause problems when other user would call the sp at the same time expecting actual data?

Comment: It is only for the current session. You would need to set it to OFF when you are done in order to get results back from the database again. I just read that it was deprecated as of 2012, so I would avoid it if possible.

Comment: Thanks, I just tested the first option and this is perfect. I just have to translate the output to DataSet columns.